# How to save namespaces of XML in dictoinary in Python and Lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have a XML file with many namespaces:

> ```
> <root xmlns:ser="https://some_address" xmlns:mirror="https://some_mirror_address">
>    <ser:use server="some_server_address"/>
>    <mirror:use default="some_mirror_address"/>
> </root>
> ```

I am using lxml and python to parse this type of file.
Now, My requirement is, When I parse this XML file I need to store all namespaces in a dictionary like:

```
nsd = {'ser' : 'https://some_address', 'mirror' : 'https://some_mirror_address'}
```

The intention of this, the namespaces are not predetermined. So When I parse the XML I need to store all the namespaces in a dictionary and then proceed with further activities.

Is this possible to achieve in lxml?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the etree api, for a given element, you can access the `nsmap` property. This holds a dictionary like what you're looking for.